# How to show only avg and max values in labels on Y axis using MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I have graph which show speed value on Y axis. I want to show exactly 2 values: avg value (i. e. middle value label) and max value. I'm using `YAxis.setLabelCount(2)` to set only two labels on Axis. But graph always showing me min value and another one or two values. The behavior that i want:

If we have max speed 2.4 miles (or km) - show label with max speed. Also show half from this speed label (1.2)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAxis.setLabelCount(2, true) there is another paramerter called force, by set it as true, the axis will have the exactly number as label count you set.

Updated July 19th:
To display label on special value, the ValueFormatter can be invoked, and the entries labels can be changed manually. It's better to change the entries of labels after it is updated by MPChart, but I cannot found the actual callback or something else which is "after the entries is updated", so I changed it in ValueFormatter, also works:

```
object: ValueFormatter() {
override fun getAxisLabel(value: Float, axis: AxisBase): String {
  axis.mEntries[0] = mAverage
  axis.mEntries[1] = mMax
  return getFormattedValue(value)
}

override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float) = String.format("%.1f", value)
```

}

Do make sure mAverage and mMax is in the range of y-axis labels!

Comment: Yeah I saw that in docs. But if i will use it i will get labels on `-0.1` somehow and max value `2.4` :(

Comment: Sorry I didn't read question fullly, the answer updated, the entries of -1 or 2.4 is calcuated by MPChart, it can be customized in ValueFormatter. @SoulReaver313

Comment: How can i get this `mAverage` and `mMax` values? I don't have those :( is it calculated manually?

Comment: Yes it should be calculated manually, the min and max value is set to y-axis, and mAverage and mMax values should be in the range of [min , max]. Because you create the chart and the average and max should be able to calculated. @SoulReaver313

Comment: Yeah but where can i get data to calculate this values? Straight from `LineDataSet`?

Comment: Yes surely, the LineDataSet is where you can get data. LineDataSet can not be visited by the function parameters, so it can be passed  to ValueFormatter as a member parameter. Or you can pass the chartView to ValueFormatter, then everything is accessable. @SoulReaver313